# lose data after adding new column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge name and surname from two columns and add this as a new column. I can do it but once its done I lost 16K rows and this new column with full name should be applied to all rows I have in the file.

Anyone knows why this might happen?

This is the code I used to create additional column:

```
FullName = Trainings['First Name']+" "+Trainings['Last Name']
Trainings.insert(5, 'Full Name', FullName, True)
```

After that I lost the data and this new column was applied to 5 rows.

Comment: if you don't share the relevant part of your code then no one can see what you are doing wrong

Comment: Please, read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples and edit your question accordingly. It is not possible for us to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it:

```
df['fullname'] = df['first'] + df['last']
```

Taking into account that these are your column names.
This way no data should be lost

Comment: Well the data is lost.

Comment: Post sample of your dataframe before and after this line of code